# How to setup this rewrite for nginx?

Tags: nginx

Help me please. How to setup this rewrite for nginx 1.0.14?

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&act=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([[:alnum:]]{8})/*$ /index.php?page=paste&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite

Something like:

```
rewrite ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?page=$1 last;
rewrite ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)/$ /index.php?page=$1&act=$2 last;
rewrite ^([[:alnum:]]{8})/*$ /index.php?page=paste&id=$1 last;
return 403;
```